# Create specific environment in Google Colab notebook

Tags: python, export, load, google-colaboratory, development-environment

I am working a lot in Google Colab notebooks. Recently I noticed, that some functions which I'm using in my code, don't work anymore. The reason was an upgrade in the version, which causes problems. Therefore I would like to freeze my environment once I finished my work in the notebook.

1. How can I save my environment in Google Colab?
2. How can I load my environment in Google Colab?
3. Any best practices?